# Why doesn't the C++ STL implement more efficient std::set implementation?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, set

**Background** 
Im building a performance minded application and I came across a place where I have to use `std::set`. And it works like a charm. But then I started reading into the documentation (which you can find [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)) and the first thing I noticed was that

> Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity. Sets are usually implemented as red-black trees.

The search, removal and insertions makes perfect sense to me as they are using *some kind of a* tree structure (because the documentation does not guarantee that it uses a [Red-Black Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)). But the problem is, why should they?

I made an alternate solution to the `std::set` of my own and which uses a `std::vector` to store all the entries. Then I performed some basic benchmarks and here are the results,

```
Iterations: 100000

// Insertion
VectorSet :   211464us
std::set  :  1272864us

// Find/ Lookup
VectorSet : 404264us
std::set  : 551464us

// Removal
VectorSet : 254321964us
std::set  :    834664us

// Traversal (iterating through all the elements (100000 elements; 100000 iterations)
VectorSet :       2464us
std::set  : 4374174264us
```

According to these results, my implementation (`VectorSet`) outperformed `std::set` in both insertions and lookups, and traversal was over 1800000 times. But `std::set` outperformed my implementation `VectorSet` by a significant margin (which is understandable as we are dealing with vectors).

I can justify why removal is slower in `VectorSet` but faster on `std::set` and why `std::set` takes so long to iterate through the entries. Some things which affect the performance would be (correct me if im wrong),

- Cache misses.
- Pointer dereferences.
- Better locality.

For the vector being slower in removal,

- Finding the element.
- Removal of the element.
- Possible resize.

---

**Question** 
As what I can see, using a `std::vector` to store entries rather than a tree structure performs better in  3/4 instances. And even in the place where `std::set` performed better, it is still a small amount compared to iterating through. And in my opinion, developers use other aspects (lookups, insertions and iterations) more than removals. Even though these numbers are in the range of nanoseconds, the slightest improvement is better.

So my question is, why does `std::set` use a tree structure when they can use something like a vector to improve their efficiency?

Note: The container will be filled up with an average of 1000 elements and will be iterated repeatedly throughout the application lifetime and will directly affect the application runtime.

Comment: "So my question is, why does std::set use a tree structure when they can use something like a vector to improve their efficiency?" Why do you use `std::set` when you can use `std::vector`?

Comment: Your compiler's optimizer deleted your traversal test because it realized it didn't do anything. You were timing how long it takes to do nothing. Even cache misses aren't 1.8 million times slower than cache hits.

Comment: This is well know (memory locality) see 45:50 in https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661  tested up to about 100,000 entries  - the pre-fetcher is doing most of the work for you if you use `std::vector`

Comment: By the way, also try unordered_set.

Comment: And, if you are testing in Visual Studio, make sure to set it to release mode.

Comment: @Slava It have to rule out duplicates and is better to be more-or-less ordered.

Comment: @user253751 Yes I timed it in release mode.

Comment: Also try measuring it with different numbers of elements. Say 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 and 1000000

Comment: How you test insertion matters. `std::set` will have logarithmic time complexity for insertion at random positions. `std::vector` will have linear time complexity for insertion at random positions but amortized constant time complexity when inserting sorted elements.

Comment: you are confusing complexity, which is about letting some `N` go to infinity, and actual runtime for a fixed value of `N`. Also it is not just one operation that makes a container efficient or not. Rather it is a tradeoff between complexity of all the operations.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The way I implemented the `VectorSet` is, binary search and find the lower bound where the element should be in the container. So as far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong), insertions, lookups will take (theoretically) `O(log n)`.

Comment: @D-RAJ If you use binary search, then the elements need to be sorted. That implies that when you insert an element, you need to insert it at its sorted position. In `std::vector` inserting at position `n` requires all elements at `n` and after to be moved 1 position down individually to make room for the new element. On average, you need to move `size() / 2` elements each insertion or removal. This gives linear complexity for those operations.

Comment: Consider that memory access is so significant for performance that `std::vector`s data locality can make it more efficient than other containers even if the other container seems to be more appropriate by looking only at complexity. `std::list` is a good example, I didnt encounter a case where `std::vector` wasnt the better alternative, unless I need stable iterators

Comment: The standard library containers perform passably well on general case. If you need to squeeze last performance out for your special case then you can compare with containers in Boost.Container and Boost.Intrusive. There is close to zero likelihood that some self-made container will win all of those for some concrete usage.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh yeah.. That makes perfect sense! OMG how did I miss it. But inserting a node is easier faster than inserting an element to a vector right..? But why is it slow here?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Owh.. Yeah... Im starting to see the bigger picture...

Comment: @D-RAJ Time complexity eventually overcomes other performance concerns *as the N variable approaches infinity*. If a better complexity solution has higher flat overhead, it may be outperformed by the "worse" solution until the size reaches that break-even point. `std::vector` has extremely good performance because of things you named, so you may need a very large data set to see the benefits of `std::set`'s better complexities.

Comment: flat_set is currently going through the standardization process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard `set` has some guarantees that you can't provide with your implementation:

- inserting/erasing doesn't invalidate other iterators/references/pointers.
- inserting/erasing elements has (at most) logarithmic complexity, as opposed to linear in your implementation.

If these don't matter to you, you're welcome to use a sorted vector and binary search. The standard provides `std::sort`, `std::vector` and `std::binary_search`, so you are good to go. The thing to notice is that each container has a specific use case and there is no "one size fits all" container.

The standard also provides `unordered_set`, which is a hash table. It is often criticized for being slow and causing cache-misses. Well, if that degrades your performance in a way you identified as a bottle-neck, go ahead and use some other hash-set implementation from other libraries. If you believe that you can do better, go ahead. Many projects build their own containers that are more specialized to that project. Could be faster, use less memory, could give different guarantees about iterator invalidation and/or complexity of operations. They all solve different problems.

---

Another point is that profiling and benchmarking is hard. Make sure you get it right. Performance comparison is usually done at scale (with varying number of input arguments). Picking a constant and relatively small size won't tell the whole story.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and it clears out all my doubts. And yes I should have stress tested it a little more.